# Как после нажатия "Back" возвращать отображение отсчета таймеров в Listview

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть listview, где каждый таймер это отдельный поток, в нем и ведется отсчет времени. Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю кнопку "Назад", активити с listview дропается, и при желании вернуться на нее, создаться новый ее экземпляр. Таймеры продолжают отсчет, но не отображают его.

В адаптере я передаю классу модели, Таймеру, объект ViewHolder, так осуществляется независимое друг от друга отображения отсчета.

Как мне возвращать отображения времени на таймерах после нажатия Back.

Фрагмент класса Таймера:

```
 class TrackerThread extends Thread{
    public TrackerThread() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            while (isStart){
            if (isStart && startTime != 0) {
                if (elapsedTime != 0 && updateTime == 0)
                    lastPause = elapsedTime;
                updateTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + lastPause);
                seconds = updateTime / 1000;
                minutes = seconds / 60;
                hours = minutes / 60;

                seconds = seconds % 60;
                minutes = minutes % 60;
                hours = hours % 24;
                elapsedTime = updateTime;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

                if(limitTime!=0 && elapsedTime > limitTime) {
                    interrupt();
                }else
                    sleep(1000);
            }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d("myTag","handleMessage");
            holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d",days));
            holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
            holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
            holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));

        if(limitTime!=0 && elapsedTime>limitTime) {
            isFinished = true;
            holder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RemindMe.db.execSQL(Util.concat("UPDATE trackers SET isFinish=1, elapsedTime=",limitTime," WHERE _id=",getId()));
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Что у вас происходит при нажатии "Назад"? Происходит выход из активити?

Comment: Попробуйте переопределить метод onBackPressed() в активности. Он отвечает за действие по нажатию кнопки назад.

Comment: @АлександрКощеев
Происходит переход на другую активити, и соответственно у той активити на которой мы находились вызывается onDestroy().

Comment: @ViR
Хм, да можно сделать что-бы не переходило на другую активити. Но суть ведь в том, как заставить новый экземпляр активити отображать данные

Comment: Таймер должен "заснуть" при разрушении акитивити или он должен продолжать отсчитывать время?

Comment: @АлександрКощеев таймер должен продолжать отсчитывать время, это тайм-менеджмент приложение, предполагается, что пользователь нажмет на старт, и дальше может ходить по приложению, либо же просто положить смарфон в карман и тд. В любом случае активити уничтожиться, вопрос как передать в новую активити отсчет времени. Если пользователь нажмет старт(запускам таймер) и уйдет с активити и потом захочешь вернуться, создаться новый экземпляр(новые потоки, новые таймеры), в общем все новое. Нужно или как-то иметь только один экемпляр этой активити(launchMode=singleInstance позволяет разрушать активити

Comment: Вам нужна сущность, которая не зависит от активити, в которой можно хранить ссылки на ваши потоки. Используйте сервис.

Comment: А вообще, какая необходимость в этих потоках? Что-то должно случиться по истечению заданного промежутка времени? Хотя, это уже вопрос архитектуры.

Comment: @АлександрКощеев
Сущность "таймер" хранит в себе ссылку на свой поток. Есть два вида таймеров, без лимита и с лимитом, в последнем случае таймер дойдет до нужной отметки и все. Пока еще не реализовано, но предполагается, что будет динамический вывод данных каждого таймера на диаграмму, которая будет показывать в режиме реального времени анализ работы таймеров.

Comment: а что вы будете делать, если девайс перезагрузится? куда денутся все эти потоки?

Comment: @АлександрКощеев, хм, даже не знаю теперь, можно их конечно перезапустить, но это не самый лучший выход

Answer (score 2):

Архитектура приложения не идеальна, но если у кого-то будут подобные проблемы(в сущность я передаю объект `ViewHolder` который будет отвечать за отображение, в ней(сущности) лежит класс `Thread` в котором происходят вычисления, и который посылает сообщения `Handler'у`, который в свою очередь уже выводить значения на экран используя упомянутый выше `ViewHolder`, но если выйти из активити вызовется `OnDestroy()` и вернуться, получается, что мы теряем связь с UI, потоки работают но т.к. это уже новый экземпляр activity/adapter и тд данные не будут отображаться).

Выход из этой ситуации таков:

Адаптер получал на вход список сущностей, в `getView()` из списка выбиралась конкретная и с ней уже проводились операции. Список этот я сделал статичным. В адаптере дописал всего одну строчку

```
tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
```

Эта строчка отвечает за связь UI с второстепенным потоком. Да, вот так просто.

Вот фрагмент моего адаптера

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
    final Thread thread = tracker.getThread();
    ViewHolder holder;
    long days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    long eDays,eHours,eMins,eSecs;

    if(row == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
        holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
        holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        holder.start = (ButtonFloatSmall)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        holder.stop = (ButtonFloatSmall)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        holder.textFinish = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtFinish);
        holder.textLimit = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLimit);
        holder.limDay = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limDay);
        holder.limHours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limHours);
        holder.limMin = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limMin);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //изнальначальный вид
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    finalHolder.name.setText(tracker.getName());

    if(tracker.getElapsedTime()!=0 && tracker.getLimitTime()==0){//если прошедшее время !=0 и таймер без лимита
        days = tracker.getElapsedTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;
        if(days!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days));
        if(hours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <=9 ?0:"",hours));
        if(minutes!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(seconds!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
    }
    if(tracker.getIsFinished()){//если таск закончен, дошел до лимита
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getLimitTime()/1000)%60;
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(seconds!=60)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
        if(minutes!=60)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(hours!=24)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours));

    }
    if(tracker.getLimitTime()!=0 && !tracker.getIsFinished()){//если установлен лимит, но еще не дошел до конца
        days = tracker.getLimitTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days, ":"));
        finalHolder.limHours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));
        finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));

        eDays = (tracker.getElapsedTime() / 86400000);
        eHours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        eMins = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        eSecs = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;

        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(eSecs<=9?0:"",eSecs));
        if(eMins!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",eMins));
        if(eHours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours<= 9 ? 0 : "", eHours));
        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days<= 9 ? 0 : "", eDays));


    }else {
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(tracker.getIsStart() && !tracker.getIsFinished()) {//если был стартован
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btStart:
                    tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    tracker.setIsStart(true);
                    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(tracker.getUpdateTime()==0)
                        thread.start();
                    else
                        tracker.getThread().start();

                    break;
                case R.id.btStop:
                    tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tracker.setIsStart(false);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    finalHolder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    finalHolder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}
```